# Apache - Some PNG images aren't showing

Tags: apache, ubuntu, png, apache2.4, ubuntu-22.04

I have a web server with Apache that I use to show images.
You can access those images directly through a URL, ex: image.com/ad.png.
This works for 106 of our images but not for the last 4.
[The ones who aren't working are in the red rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfIYh.png)

[This is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWUR.png)

Server: Ubuntu 22.04.3
Apache: 2.4.52

I've restarted the server and Apache service, but that didn't help.
And I haven't found anything via Google that could be the solution.

The image should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different attempts nothing worked except to install a fresh new Ubunto server and that solved the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you had a permission problem, did you check that out ?

https://serverfault.com/a/357109